# Why won't my program run from the Program Files directory but will from anywhere else?

Tags: .net, windows

My program run fine from anywhere else on my drive apart from the Program Files directory (windows XP), I am logged on as administrator so I have full permissions to the drive. It runs fine from the root of c: the windows directory basically anywhere else apart from Program Files. I have recreated this problem on 4 different machines 2 XP, 2 Vista.

My program is a C# .Net 2.0 program. What on earth could the problem be?

I have even copied my entire project to the Program Files directory and I can't debug it from there it just won't run up, no errors at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you verified that it's just this program than can't run in program files? Can you create a small "dummy app" that runs in program files?

Comment: You should close this question if you have found your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, but if your program tries to save data to the program-directory, Vista will prevent this and change the path dynamically to something like c:\users[user]\AppData. Maybe this gives you a hint on whats going on.

Otherwise we need more info on your program to help you.

Comment: He has this problem in 2 machines with XP.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't debug, you can always create a debug log. It is a bit slow, but in the end you will find the place where the program stops working.

```
LogDebug('before 1');
Statement1;
LogDebug('before 2');
Statement2;
LogDebug('before 3');
Statement3;
LogDebug('after 3');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the program on a fresh XP install that doesn't have any orgranizational policies applied.

:-(

Comment: Ouch!  Have you tried with the .PDB file in the same directory yet?

Comment: Yes and it didn't make any difference, I also set the debug location to the program files folder and it won't run, change it to anywhere else and it runs fine. I'm puzzled.

Comment: Maybe some of the information at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx can help you pinpoint where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The program does run from other folders with a space in the path such as Documents and Settings, the program does create a temporary file in the user profile\appdata folder.

If I run the app several time from somewhere it will run from I've just noticed I get an error with the option to debug but VS won't show me the location of the problem I just get the error belo.

Unhandled exception at 0x79fb96a2 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000c.

The problem can be recreated on XP and Vista.

Many thanks

Comment: Put the .PDB file in the same directory.  You should get better information.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a machine managed by your company's "big brother", it sounds like only "allowed" applications can run from "Program files"

Answer (score 0):

What does your programm read in its directory?

Why are you creating a temp file in user/appdata?
For temporary files, you should use the API to get the temporary folder for the current profile and ideally an temporary filename, works like this:

```
string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetTempFileName());
```

To help you properly, we need to know what your program should do on init.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any thing like Anti-virus software running?

Which is it?

- Is it not running (probably OS related)
- OR is it falling over  (probably permissions)
- OR running and not producing expected output? (probably permissions)

Have you checked the Event Logs?

Try calling it from a batch file and see what happens.

uhmm anyone want to try his .exe on their machine??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this but I found the problem, I had some crap code that was looking for arguments being passed including 'file' and the file in 'program files' was forcing the program into a command line mode that has no gui. Really sorry to have wasted your time on such a trivial problem, you live and learn!

Thanks to all.